# ctr and docker sharing the namespace

Tags: docker, namespaces, containerd

I want to use snapshotters like `stargz` for starting the containers faster. The existing system is docker based and the stargz snapshotter is supported by containerd (ctr) CLI and not by the existing version of docker CLI. So I used ctr commands to pull and start the containers.

Now in the the existing system there are some docker related commands that try to detect the number of running containers, number of images etc. I **do not** want to change those but just wanted to let new containers coming up use the snapshotter.  I read somewhere that docker uses `moby` namespace by default and ctr uses `default` namespace. So I tried pulling the images and creating containers in moby namespace. But when I am executing `docker images` I am not seeing any newly pulled image.

```
sudo ctr -n moby image pull test_image:latest

sudo ctr  -n moby images ls
REF                                                                                TYPE                                                      DIGEST                                                                  SIZE    PLATFORMS                  LABELS 
test_image:latest application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:f10117329dcc584f8edcda119395ea3b33afd232e3ec27034688babe76b16898 1.2 GiB linux/amd64,linux/arm64/v8 -  



docker images ---> no images listed.
REPOSITORY                                                   TAG                       IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
```

Please note I can see vice versa is true - meaning if there is a running container seen in `docker ps -a` then I can see it using ctr command

```
sudo ctr -n moby containers ls
CONTAINER                                                           IMAGE    RUNTIME                  
9825c1832b5196d2d18b090f45c5191688ee61322e983361697e7282efd218bb    -        io.containerd.runc.v2    
sudo ctr -n moby tasks ls
TASK                                                                PID      STATUS    
9825c1832b5196d2d18b090f45c5191688ee61322e983361697e7282efd218bb    16320    RUNNING
```

Is there any way to share the namespace between `docker` and `ctr`?